# Gson is resetting values for fields that do not come back in the JSON. Workarounds?

Tags: android, json, gson

Seems to a bug filed here: https://github.com/google/gson/issues/513

The trouble is I don't know any workarounds, I am fairly new to Gson. I have a boolean field in my POJO that I set myself, it doesn't come in the JSON, I set to `true`, and when the object is parsed by Gson, its' set back to `false`. Behaviour that should not be happening.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                        .serializeNulls()
                        .setExclusionStrategies(new ExclusionStrategy() {
                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldSkipField(FieldAttributes f) {
                                return f.getName().equals("reviewed");
                            }

                            @Override
                            public boolean shouldSkipClass(Class<?> clazz) {
                                return false;
                            }
                        })
                        .create();
```

As you can see I have tried skipped the field `reviewed`, however it's still being set to `false`. I've also tried adding breakpoints inside the `shouldSkipField` method and it does indeed return `true` when it tries to parse `reviewed`. So I really don't understand, all I can chalk it up to is the bug I posted above.

Does anyone have a better solution? It seems the bug has been around for a while.

Appreciate the help.

Edit:

Here is how it looks in my POJO

```
private boolean reviewed;

//Getters and setters
public boolean isReviewed() {
    return reviewed;
}

public void setReviewed(boolean reviewed) {
    this.reviewed = reviewed;
}
```

Comment: How does your `reviewed` field really look like? Is it a primitive `boolean` or a wrapper `Boolean`? And does it have any initializers?

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv updated my question, set the Boolean to primitives but that did not fix it.

Comment: It's because primitive fields aways gets default values.

Comment: Always? even when I set the value? This is where i feel the GSON bug is, it's setting it back to it's default, because it's not in the json. Even though I ignored it

Comment: @RED_ It's not a Gson bug despite it's filed as a bug. Gson ignores missing fields (see its https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/gson/src/main/java/com/google/gson/internal/bind/ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java implementation). Your `reviewed` is always `false` because primitive booleans can only hold bi-state, and `false` is the default value for boolean primitives. Once you change the initializer to `= true`, Gson will still ignore it and you `isReviewed()` will return `true`. You need tri-state, like `Boolean` where its default value is `null`.

Comment: I've set it to be a Boolean object, with it's tri-state but that hasn't solved the issue, the reviewed field is now always null.

Comment: @RED_ I'm confused. `null` is the default value for the referential types fields: and this is fine because it proves that Gson does not touch the field. You said: _ I have a boolean field in my POJO that I set myself, it doesn't come in the JSON, I set to true_ -- according to the code you have provided, it looks like you're setting the field to `true` elsewhere, but not in the field initializer. When you deserialize, a _new_ object is created, your `true` value is lost. I'm curious, but do you want deserialize _into_ an existing object that already has the `reviewed` field set to true?

Comment: @RED_ or: what Gson version are you using?

Comment: Ok I understand. I do want to deserialize into an existing object, rather than recreating it everytime. I guess I lose GSON's automatic parsing if I do that, but I will give it a try. I'm using GSON 2.8.0

Comment: @RED_ Now it's much more clear. :) Gson does not deserialize into existing objects -- it always creates new ones, so you have to manage the original to deserialized object state copying yourself (you choose the implementation itself) even if you dislike the fact that new objects are created (but this is really a good design choice). Regarding the filed bug: perhaps it was really a valid issue the other day, but it definitely cannot be reproduced in Gson 2.8.0.

Comment: @LyubomyrShaydariv Thanks. This has solved this issue, and helped me understand more about GSON. Please add your own answer and I will make it as the official answer.

Comment: @RED_ I'm glad I could help you out. Since your question becomes clear in the comments only, perhaps it's better if you award https://stackoverflow.com/a/44634671/166589 -- Abdallah suggested you exactly the same before I even realized what your problem is. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gson does not really "reset" the field to its default value. It actually creates a new instance from the class you provide for it. and then sets all the fields that come from json to your object.

Here's what you should do. You have to set the `reviewed` field in the same instance that is returned from the json.